# Why does the following code sort the List of objects?

Tags: java, list, object, collections

Could you please explain why the following code compiles and prints [1, 2, 3, 4], as expected. I'm using Java 8.

```
List nums = Arrays.asList(4, 3, 2, 1);
Collections.sort(nums);
System.out.println(nums);
```

As I understand, four Integer instances is created here. Each list entry contains an Object reference to an Integer instance. Since the Object class doesn't implement the Comparable interface, then Collections.sort should throw ClassCastException or something like this because it cannot cast Object references to Comparable references.

Could you please point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Since you're on Java 8, please use *generics*: `List<Integer> nums`, which also answers your question.

Comment: You can't have a Collection of primitives in Java, so they are auto-boxed into their equivalent type. `int` is auto-boxed to `Integer` which DOES implement comparable.

Comment: Ultimately they are objects only when being added to list. Integer class objects they are. Integer class implements comparable interface. So ultimately its Integer, not just Object

Comment: So, as I understood, sort function cast each Object entry to Integer and since Integer implements Comparable everything works fine.

Comment: If you put some custom objects in your array and class of these custom objects if doesn't implement comparable, you will get the error. Ultimately if you don't declare the type of objects to list then type of objects shall be checked at runtime. And their run time type is integer

Comment: There is a big difference between type of a reference and type of an object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With 1,2,3,4 you are creating `int` literals. While passing them to `asList(T... a)` they get boxed into `Integer` objects which implements `Comparable` (`public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>`), so you can sort them.

**Update**

Comment: Yes, but the List is declared as List, so it's the synonym to `List<Object>`, not `List<Integer>`, and `Object` doesn't implement `Comparable`.

Answer: You do not specify a generic type for the list and the `Collections.sort()` method only checks if the object's class extends `Comparable`. If the list has no type, your compiler should only give you a warning and everything should work fine since `Integer`'s are comparable.

**The source code of the sort method**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Execute this piece of code to see what happens if the class does not implements `Comparable`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List objs = new ArrayList<>();
        objs.add(new Test());
        objs.add(new Test());
        Collections.sort(objs);
    }
}
```

The cast to `Comparable` which is done in Line 290 of `ComparableTimSort.class` will fail!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: src.Test cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at src.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Comment: Yes, but the List is declared as List, so it's the synonym to List<Object>, not List<Integer>, and Object doesn't implement Comparable.

Comment: @savak `List` is not a synonym for `List<Object>`. `List` basically turns off all generic features. It's intended for code that was written before generics existed. Checking that T extends Comparable is one of the checks that doesn't happen when you're not using generics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was definitely think that List and List<Object> are the same declaration.

Comment: generics is kind of declaration that you are going to add this type of objects into your list. And if you add some thing different then it will show error. This information is not available at run time. Its actually the class type of object that decides the behavior.

Comment: As a side note, even if you really have a `List<Object>`, you can bypass the Generic compile-time test using `Collections.sort(list, null)` as a `null` comparator implies “natural order” but `null` is also assignable to `Comparator<Object>` without an error. That’s a glitch in the API…

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between type of a reference and actual type of an object it points to.

```
Integer i = 42;
Object o = i;
System.out.println(i.getClass());
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
```

Both `i` and `o` point to an object (or value) whose runtime type is always Integer. Pointing to the object using a reference of a more general type doesn't affect its properties or behaviour in any way. This is how polymorphism works in Java.

Therefore, both of these assignments work:

```
Comparable<Integer> c1 = i;
Comparable<Integer> c2 = (Comparable<Integer>) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using native integer, the autobox will automatically convert it to java.lang.Integer (which implements comparable). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Yes, but the List is declared as List, so it's the synonym to List<Object>, not List<Integer>, and Object doesn't implement Comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a casting problem. Initially create a integer array and then you have converted into list. I hope this one is helpful for you.

```
    Integer[] number=new Integer[]{4,3,2,1};
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(number));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece here is type erasure.

Java compiles to JVM bytecode, and JVM bytecode has no concept of generics. So at runtime, a `List` is precisely the same as a `List<Comparable>` or a `List<Object>`. If your code ever contained that information (which your code doesn't), then it is erased when your code is compiled.

This means that at runtime, there's no difference between a `List<Object>` and a `List<Comparable>`, other than the actual elements they contain (as a consequence, it also means that if your `List` contains no elements, then there's no way of telling what sort of `List` it was meant to be).

`Collections.sort` is able to sort any `List` whose elements all implement `Comparable`, and are comparable with each other. Since your `List` contains `Integer`s, which implement `Comparable`, `Collections.sort` is able to sort it.

Perhaps confusingly, this isn't true of arrays, for historical reasons. `Comparable[]` and `Object[]` are completely different types. In principle, this means that Java's array sorting methods could refuse to sort `Object[]` arrays, as you might expect. In practice they do not, and `Arrays.sort` accepts `Object[]` arrays, analogously to `Collections.sort`.